# Elgg Headers in http request not allowed

Tags: angularjs, http, cors, elgg, angular-http-interceptors

I am developing a frontend application in AngularJS, an i'am trying to login in a elgg platform.
As described in the documentation [here](http://learn.elgg.org/en/latest/guides/web-services/hmac.html) if you want to use HMAC auth, you have to add some custom headers. And in AngularJS I have used interceptors.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, HMAC){
    return {
        // optional method
        'request': function(config) {
            // do something on success
            console.log("Interceptor Config-> ",config);
            console.log("HTTP? --> ",config.url.indexOf('http'));

            if(config.url.indexOf('http') == 0){
                //do something only on http requests
                config.headers = config.headers || {};

                config.headers['X-Elgg-apikey'] = "";
                config.headers['X-Elgg-time'] = "";
                config.headers['X-Elgg-none'] = "";
                config.headers['X-Elgg-hmac'] = "";
                config.headers['X-Elgg-hmac-algo'] = "";

            }

            console.log("Return -->", config);
            return config || $q.when(config);
        }
    };
});
```

But the response the response i got is :

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/elgg-1.9.8/elgg-1.9.8/services/api/rest/xml/?method=auth.gettoken. 
Request header field X- Elgg-hmac-algo is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

I have apache on my webserver on localhost and i have configured :
`<Directory />
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Request-Headers "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Request-Method "*"
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>`

I have also checked the response header and this what i got :

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 30 May 2015 13:37:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Request-Headers: *
Access-Control-Request-Method: *
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.3
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Fri, 05 Feb 1982 00:00:00 -0500
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 81
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

I can't find where is the bug. I setted the headers response on the server but i still got this error on console.
Thanks

Comment: Is there really a space after X- , or is that just my phone?

Comment: same here ( on desktop ) there is a space.